# Print factor analysis from factanal() with item labels

Tags: r

**EDIT**

So it looks like it's something in my call to `library(reshape)` that's breaking the labeling of factors. This was not included in the minimal example, but will be added now. It's not needed to create the example, but it's needed to recreate the issue. I need the library to get my data in shape to even do `factanal()`. Any ideas what part of reshape is breaking it and how to fix it?

---

**Original question**

I have been running factor analyses on my data and have been having an intermittent issue with the way results are printed.

If I create a data set like the following:

```
library(reshape)
mock <- data.frame(
  sample_name1 = sample(1:100),
  sample_name2 = sample(1:100),
  sample_name3 = sample(1:100),
  s_amplename_4 = sample(1:100),
  samplename5 = sample(1:100),
  sa_mplen_a_me_6 = sample(1:100),
  samplename7 = sample(1:100),
  samplename8 = sample(1:100)
)
```

and run a factor analysis with

```
factanal(mock, factors = 2)
```

I get the output to print out very prettily with item names as labels for the rows, e.g.:

```
# Snip snip
Loadings:
                Factor1 Factor2
sample_name1    -0.126  -0.105 
sample_name2    -0.414         
sample_name3     0.665         
s_amplename_4           -0.314 
samplename5              0.850 
sa_mplen_a_me_6 -0.117         
samplename7      0.442         
samplename8     -0.139
```

This kind of output is exactly what I am looking for. However, when I run the same type of analysis on my own data (and I apologize for the length here):

```
miniset <- structure(list(`clarity1` = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 4.5, 1.5, 1.5, 3.5, 
                                           2, 6, 2.5, 4, 1, 1.5, 6, 2, 5.5, 2, 2, 3, 1.5, 5, 3.5, 2, 1.5, 
                                           2.5, 3, 3, 2, 1), 
                          `clarity2` = c(1.5, 2, 2, 2, 3.5, 5, 3, 5, 
                                           2, 4, 2, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3.5, 6, 1, 2, 1.5, 1, 2, 
                                           2, 3, 6.5, 1), 
                          `clarity3` = c(3, 3.5, 2, 3.5, 5.5, 4, 6, 5.5, 
                                           2, 3, 3, 3.5, 1, 2.5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2, 6.5, 5.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 3, 
                                           2, 2, 5, 4.5, 5.5), 
                          `detail1` = c(3, 4, 2, 6, 5, 6.5, 5.5, 
                                          4, 3, 6, 2.5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4.5, 7, 6.5, 2, 6.5, 6, 2, 6, 5, 2.5, 
                                          5.5, 4, 5.5, 6, 1.5), 
                          `detail2` = c(3.5, 4, 4, 6.5, 4.5, 6, 
                                          4, 4.5, 2, 6, 2.5, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6, 7, 7, 2, 6.5, 6, 3, 6, 6, 2.5, 
                                          6, 3, 5, 6.5, 2.5), 
                          `detail3` = c(2.5, 4, 2, 6, 5, 6, 6, 4, 
                                          2, 6, 2, 5, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6.5, 6, 2, 6.5, 7, 7, 5.5, 5, 3.5, 2, 
                                          3, 5, 6, 2), 
                          `complete1` = c(2, 2.5, 2, 3, 3.5, 5.5, 2.5, 2.5, 
                                            2, 3, 3, 3.5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 7, 4, 2, 3, 6, 3, 5.5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
                                            3, 6, 3), 
                          `complete2` = c(3, 4.5, 2, 3, 4.5, 6, 6, 4.5, 3, 
                                            3, 3.5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 4, 2, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 
                                            2), 
                          `complete3` = c(3, 4.5, 2, 2.5, 4.5, 6.5, 5, 5, 2, 6.5, 
                                            3.5, 3.5, 1, 3, 3, 2.5, 7, 4, 2, 6, 1.5, 7, 5.5, 6.5, 3.5, 5.5, 
                                            3, 3, 2.5, 1), 
                          `truthful1` = c(2.5, 2, 2, 3, 3.5, 2, 2, 2.5, 
                                            2, 3, 3, 2.5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3.5, 3, 2, 3.5, 1.5, 1, 3.5, 2.5, 3, 
                                            2, 2, 3, 1.5, 1.5), 
                          `truthful2` = c(2.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 3, 1.5, 
                                            2, 1, 1, 5.5, 3, 3.5, 1, 4.5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1.5, 4.5, 1, 3.5, 
                                            2, 3.5, 2.5, 2, 2, 4.5, 1), 
                          `truthful3` = c(2, 1.5, 2, 3.5, 
                                            2.5, 2, 2, 2.5, 2, 2, 3.5, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2, 3.5, 
                                            1, 2, 1, 3.5, 2, 2, 2.5, 4.5, 1), 
                          `relevant1` = c(1.5, 1.5, 
                                            2, 5, 2.5, 1.5, 2, 3.5, 2, 4.5, 2.5, 3.5, 1, 3.5, 3, 1.5, 5.5, 
                                            3.5, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3.5, 3, 1.5, 2, 3, 3, 6, 1), 
                          `relevant2` = c(1.5, 
                                            3, 2, 2, 3.5, 1.5, 2.5, 5.5, 1, 2, 3.5, 2, 1, 1.5, 2, 4, 5.5, 
                                            2, 3, 5.5, 5.5, 1, 4, 5, 1.5, 2, 3, 2.5, 3, 1), 
                          `relevant3` = c(1.5, 
                                            2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 5.5, 5, 
                                            2, 1, 7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2.5, 1)), 
                     .Names = c("clarity1", 
                                "clarity2", "clarity3", "detail1", "detail2", "detail3", 
                                "complete1", "complete2", "complete3", "truthful1", "truthful2", 
                                "truthful3", "relevant1", "relevant2", "relevant3"), 
                     row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = c("cast_df", "data.frame"))

factanal(miniset, factors = 3)
```

the result is much less pretty, e.g.:

```
Loadings:
      Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
 [1,]          0.222   0.664 
 [2,]  0.559   0.524         
 [3,]  0.824                 
 [4,]  0.740   0.361   0.282 
 [5,]  0.698   0.374   0.251 
 [6,]  0.783   0.278   0.265 
 [7,]  0.498   0.598   0.140 
 [8,]  0.796   0.227   0.204 
 [9,]  0.490  -0.240   0.835 
[10,]  0.147   0.156   0.348 
[11,]          0.697   0.324 
[12,]          0.756         
[13,]  0.319   0.811   0.204 
[14,]  0.567   0.252   0.108 
[15,]  0.320   0.690
```

So rather than having the nice item names as labels for the loadings, I now get indices. While that's fine for me, I'll be working with a professor tomorrow who is less familiar with R and will probably get frustrated by the lack of labels. So what happens to the labels in the second case? And how can I get them back?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I run your code, the output is perfectly "pretty" with labels and everything.

Comment: @joran I've further troubleshot the issue and updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `miniset` is a `cast_df` and `factanal` calls `as.matrix(x)`. The `as.matrix.cast_df` method uses `rrownames` and `rcolnames` (all `reshape` functions) to extract "special dimension names".

For `miniset` these are `NULL` (hence the rownames are lost). Without knowing how you constructed `miniset`  I can't help further here. (You must have used `reshape` to construct `miniset` at some point as you have created a `cast_df` object.

Good news is that

```
factanal(as.data.frame(miniset))
```

Works as you wish

Comment: Thanks! It's still weird to me that it works fine when I load the same structure without the `reshape` package loaded, but after loading reshape it fails. Does it revert to `as.matrix.data.frame` when no `cast_df` method is found?

Comment: @Ryan -- exactly -- `as.matrix.cast.df` is a function in the `reshape` package.